# OpenCV imread eror in python

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem with OpenCV lib in Python. I want to read image but I encounter an error. This is my image about that error. Please help me to solve. Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTksI.png

Answer (score -2):

try giving path not filename

## path

path = r'C:\Users\Prajjwal\Desktop\sample.png'

## Using cv2.imread() method

img = cv2.imread(path)

Comment: I tried to do like that but it didn't work.